# how to call on resume when activity is destroyed?

Tags: android, android-activity, onresume

I have activity A which creates list view and has `onResume` action to update adapter.

```
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ma.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.d("resumed","true");
        }
```

Also I have activity B.  How can I call A's `onResume`, when B is destroyed or it pressed `back` from activity B?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will called if the resumed Activity is A:

For instance:

You are navigating from A to B:

```
A is onPause:
B is onCreate -> onResume. you do your work on B and then finish() it
A in onResume
```

Comment: Yes, i am aware that it should work this way, but  log says it did not happen.

Comment: Sorry, just did not notice that instalation of lates version vas canceled.